# How Java video can work, within a friendly installation procedure?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, applet

How can you capture Video using Java ? You have to use JMF ? In my research Audio part is solved, someone would not require Audio with JMF (in case to reduce installation headaches)

For Java Video, In my test case:

- Without JMF installed in my PC, it says package does not exist, but i have Java installed.
  import javax.media.*;
- With JMF installed in my second PC, it works. which means JAVA + JMF seperately need to be installed.

But:

- There are many users, want simple installation procedure, for example: Download -> click install -> run -> talk and watch

OR

- Many users dont follow install JAVA and then install JMF and then finally install my application to talk and watch

Solution:

- JNLP is one hope, but can i embed whole **JMF** as source for cross platform and deploy it within my application ? To minimize the installation procedure to focus user friendly installation method.
- Is there any other way arround to minimize this installations headache, and completely switch to some other class/libraries, where i can do RAW video capture for h264, compress video, text overlap, streaming etc etc ?

### Follow ups:

```
JMF Cross platform:
.
├── bin
│   ├── jmfcustomizer
│   ├── JMF.ico
│   ├── jmfinit
│   ├── jmfregistry
│   └── jmstudio
├── doc
│   ├── attributions.html
│   ├── formats.html
│   └── readme.html
└── lib
    ├── customizer.jar
    ├── jmf.jar
    ├── jmf.properties
    ├── mediaplayer.jar
    └── multiplayer.jar

3 directories, 13 files
```

Comment: I've not worked with java in a few years - but when I did the JMF was (at best) atrocious...

Comment: FYI: [Why do so many people write JAVA instead of Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2271/241)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMF can be deployed via JNLP. (1)

It would be achieved by calling the install procedure from within an installer-desc JNLP.  The installer is invoked a single time, when the app. is first launched.

As to what to do within that installer JNLP, there are two options.

One way is to call the normal installer (e.g. for Windows - that would be the .exe), but that has the disadvantage that the user would be prompted to reboot.  I checked that by not rebooting and found it to be unnecessary, but the message is irritating.  JWS can partition the download so that Windows gets the .exe, while Mac and *nix get whatever installer is appropriate to them.

The other way is to simply add the appropriate JMF Jars into the resources section of your main JNLP file, but you might need to write some code to invoke the JMFRegistry, which I think is done automatically in the installer.

1) Note:  I have tested neither method.

**Edit:**  Forgot to mention that I have a little [demo. of the ExtensionInstallerService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis) that is invoked via. the installer-desc mentioned above.

Comment: thompson: thanks, please check the follow up, that means those lib/*jar files or bin/doc folders i also need to include in my jnlp ?

Comment: I'm looking at my install of the JMF 2.1.1e - it has similar setup to what you outlined above, but only the readme.html in docs.  The readme.html includes a usage license that should be shown to the user to accept before the installation starts - if they refuse it, the installation should be aborted.  The other two docs. in your install are not directly relevant to an end user, though it might be handy to offer the formats.html.  Most of the .exe's in bin are wrappers for the Jars and can be excluded.  Many of the Jars in 'lib' are also not relevant.  Having said that, the license.. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) ..the license states that we may "distribute the Software complete and unmodified, except that you may omit those files specifically identified as"optional" in the Software "README" file".  That would probably give you a better idea of what should be left in, and what can be omitted from the JWS based install.